# Mean value theorem proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There are a lot of ways to prove the MVT; i think the most common is probably to first prove Rolle's theorem and then use it to prove the MVT despite them being the same. It can also be done directly using some epsilons and deltas or using the extreme value theorem.

I would like to find a basic as possible proof just from continuity and not the epsilon delta definition. The reason being is i would like to make it easy to understand in a first calculus class where most people don't understand this proof at all.

I am going to take the following as my definition of continuity.

Definition Continuity: A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\exists $ an open interval (a,b) s.t $ x_0 \in (a,b)$  and $f(x)$ is defined on (a,b) and the  $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$

MVT: If $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and is differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ s.t $f^{'}(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\alpha$ where alpha is a constant.

EDIT: The below statement isn't true without assuming $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable but if someone knows a simpler poof then the Rolle's to MVT and wants to post it i would love to read it.

Proof: Since $f(x)$ is differentiable we know that $f^{'}(x)$ is continuous.

Let us look at $f'(d)$ where $d\in (a,b)$. This is bigger, smaller or equal to $\alpha$ if its equal then we are done. If its not equal then it must be the case that it is larger or smaller than $\alpha$. WLOG assume that $f'(d)< \alpha$ by above we know $\exists h\in (a,b)$ s.t $f'(h)>\alpha$ (you can't have an average that is larger than every value or smaller than every value.)

Since $f'(x)$ is continuous on the interval $(a,b)$ and the interval $(d,h) \subset (a,b)$ we know that $f'(x)$ is continuous on $(d,h)$.

I would like to think that i could say since $\alpha \in (f'(d),f'(h))$ there exists a $c \in (d,h) $ s.t $f'(c)=\alpha$. Which is defiantly true, but can it be shown to be true jsut using the definition of a function and continuity? or do I need the concept of image and pre-image // prove that $f'(x)$ is onto $(f'(d),f'(h))$

Comment: The statement "If $f$ is differentiable then $f'$ is continuous" is false. Being differentiable only means that $f'$ exists at each point.

Comment: Pretty sure my definition of continuity is pointwise so why isn't it fine?

Comment: Because you are not assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: Uh great, your right i will have to make this a lot more complicated to make it work

Comment: I am surprised there's no straightforward way to prove it without using heavy analysis, no idea why they prove this in a first year calc class.

Comment: I think people have difficulty with the proof because they are learning about proofs. The intuition for Rolle's & MVT is straightforward.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah i mean i find people get the proof for Rolle's rather easily but every time i use it to prove the MVT peoples eyes glaze over and i get the feeling no one understands what i am saying.

Comment: The thing is that you only need differentiability for the theorem to hold. It is easy to prove under this assumption only, then why making stronger hypotheses?

Comment: MVT is just a "rotated" version of Rolle's Theorem. There is nothing difficult about it.

Comment: Perhaps focusing on how the problem is reduced to Rolle's might help. Although I have often found the idea of subtracting a linear term seems to throw people. It is obvious after you understand the connection between the changing slope and linear term.

Comment: Yeah i guess that's what i will have to do, thanks guys.

Comment: Keep trying. It is good to simplify if one can.

Comment: Your definition of continuity does not fit to your formulation of the MVT - unless you assume that $f$ is defined on bigger open interval $(c,d) \supset [a,b]$.

Comment: @PaulFrost uh, k can you explain why? i took both from the book introduction to real analysis by William F trench and i double checked the statements and i seem to of copied them correctly but perhaps not. would it change the meaning if i said defined on an open interval (a,b) instead of there exists an open interval (a,b) that f is define on?

Comment: @Faust "A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\exists $ an open interval $(c,d)$ s.t $ x_0 \in (c,d)$  and $f(x)$ is defined on $(c,d)$ and the  $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$." So what does it mean that  $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$? You need a bigger open interval $(c,d) \supset [a,b]$ on which $f$ is defined or $f$ cannot be continous in $x_0 =a$ and $x_0 = b$.

Comment: @Faust But see Definition 2.2.3 ! This explains it.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ah i see what your saying, however in my statement i assume that f is continous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ this directly implies your statement that f must be defined on an open interval $(c,d) \supset [a,b]$  if it was not the case then the left side and right side of the limit may not agree; which would make the assumption of continuity on the closed interval false.